# What is in Java the 'system default package'?

Tags: java

While researching the URLConnection class I stumbled on a reference to ***system default package*** in the API docs for the **URL** class [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String%2c%20java.lang.String%2c%20int%2c%20java.lang.String%29).

Anyone knows what that is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default package is basically no package at all. If you were to ommit the package declaration when defining a new class. The difference seems to be the word "system." Looking through the implementation of URL.class in rt.jars it seems to check `sun.net.www.protocol` I would guess that is the system default package it is referring to.

Again the name 'system' default package seems to imply a difference between default package.

Keep in mind `sun.net.www.protocol` is only valid for a specific implementation of the JVM by Sun.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, for the research.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it means a system-dependent package name that is used as a fallback when the first two steps fail to find an appropriate `URLStreamHandler`. It is unrelated to the *default package*.