# How Default package is created and where?

Tags: java

In this How Default Package is Created where class file is stored

```
class Package
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Default Package");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to "create" packages. They implicitly come into existence when you have a Java class with a "package" declaration at the top of the file. If you don't have a "package" declaration in your Java class, then the class goes into the default package. So this package just exists the moment that you have a class that is in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is in Java the 'system default package'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629206/what-is-in-java-the-system-default-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we create a java class and do not mention any package name for creating this particular class within any java/web project the eclipse /netbeans will automatically create the default package.

Comment: The default package is located in the source folder and basically has no name and does not need to be declared. To say that the IDE will create it isn't super accurate because that is just how the ID interprets it and is technically not really a package creation.

Answer (score 0):

The default package location is located in the source folder of your project. If we are talking about java then that is just a package without name.

You can see this even better if you try to compile things without an IDE like this

```bash
javac Package.java
```

which results in a Package.class file. And if you run:

```bash
java Package
```

You will get

```bash
Default Package
```

As expected. And as you will see, there is no package directory created and everything works.

Using Java in the command line helps a lot understanding these commands and to learn how to use it checkout out these links:

1. [The javac command for JDK 17 in the Oracle Webpage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html)
2. [The java command for JDK 17 in the Oracle Webpage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html)